# Can I test Java controllers with specs2 in Play Framework 2?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, specs2

I have an controller that is written in Java and I would like to test it using Scala with specs2. I can test my controller with JUnit and it works fine. But I am unable to test it with specs2. I have followed [the documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaFunctionalTest) and it mentions I should pass a fakeRequest as an parameter. But methods in the Java controller doesn't accept any parameters so I am unable to use this approach.

How can I test it? Only way I could think of would be using same methods as in JUnit but then using specs2 doesn't bring benefits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I have figured it out myself.

I can use helpers from `play.test.Helpers` then I use them with specs2 matchers and it works as intended.

```
import controllers.routes
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import play.test.Helpers._
import play.api.test._

class MyControllerSpec extends Specification {
  "My Controller" should {
    "respond with text/plain content type" in new WithApplication {
      val result = callAction(routes.ref.MyController.index(), fakeRequest())
      contentType(result) mustEqual "text/plain"
    }
  }
}
```